# Python HTML and re.sub

Tags: python, html

I have a code like this:

```
(some code)
x = read()

html = ''' 
<html>
<body>

<div id="wrap">
    <% name %>
    <p>Time:</p>
    <table>  
        <% hours %>
    </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
            '''
result = re.sub(r'<% hours %>', x, html)
f = open(name+'.html','w')
f.write(result)
f.close()
```

And now it prints correctly 'hours' in to HTML, but I would like to also set this <% name %> as some variable but when I add another re.sub it's not working as it should.

Is there a way to put two different parameters to html in code like above?

Edit:

Zroq solutions work for me, thanks!

Comment: Python string formatting seems to be what you are looking for https://pyformat.info/

Comment: Why don't you use a proper templating library? Three are many in Python.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I wanted to create a code without using non standard library, Zroq solution is solving my problem.

Comment: Don't edit your question to indicate you have found a solution. *Up vote* and *accept*.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?:

```
html_mapping = {'<% hours %>': 'hour something',
                '<% name %>': 'name something'}
result = re.sub(r'<% hours %>|<% name %>', lambda x: html_mapping[x.group()], html)
```